# layer name duplicated and adds geometry type

Tags: qgis, layers

When I add layers to my QGIS project, the name of the layer is listed in the Layers Panel. So far, so good.
Recently QGIS changed and now the name is repeated and the geometry type is added.
For instance, if I have a layer called RoadSegment, it is listed in the Layers Panel as RoadSegment roadsegment LineString.
It only seems to happen with shape files, not with data from my database.

How can I stop this?

I'm using QGIS 2.14.4 on a Win 7 64bit machine.

Comment: Interesting, I have seen this with other types of files such as kml. Have you tried re-saving it as a new shapefile and see if it still loads with the repetition? Also, you could consider downloading the latest QGIS 2.16 (or QGIS 2.14.6).

Comment: I've had a few bugs with version 2.14.4 that were solved in 2.14.6. @Joseph suggestion to install 2.14.6 is good I think...

Comment: Changing versions is not easy on my work PC, so I will have to live with it until we get permission to upgrade. I checked on my laptop at home with version 2.16.1 and it is fine. Thank you for the responses.

Comment: I got the same problem with .kml files on qgis 2.18.6. Any fixes for that? Got a ton of .kml which I convert to .shp using python script.